# How can I ensure that a wxFrame is brought to the foreground?

Tags: focus, wxwidgets, set

I have a `wxFrame` that receives events. Whenever an event comes in, I want the frame to be brought to the foreground.

I'm currently using:

```
my_frame->SetFocus();
```

But that doesn't seem to work for minimized frames. How can I set the frame as the active window and bring it to the front?

Alternatively, is there a method that flashes the title?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't have a useable example but have you ever tried

```
my_frame->Raise()
```

It raises the window to the top of the window hierarchy.

Comment: `frame->Iconize(false); // restore if minimized`